# what happens to Flex/Flash application after December 2020?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flex4, flex3

I understand that Adobe will stop supporting Flash in December 2020. All major browsers also might drop support after December 2020. I have a Adobe Flex/Flash application which is currently being used. What are the options I have, considering the above events?

Comment: If you need to support the app for a couple of years only, try Royale or HAXE as suggested in the other answer. However if you want a longer shelf life, bite the bullet and rewrite in Angular or React or Vue.

Comment: After confirming that there is a killswitch after 2021-JAN-12 - I found the solution outlined here to work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254243/does-the-flash-executable-itself-stop-flash-from-working-january-12-2021/65685790#65685790

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options.

First of all, if it's not essential that the app run in a browser, i.e. if it would be acceptable for it to be a desktop app, you could convert it to an Adobe AIR app.

Of course, many question how long Adobe will support AIR. They've just transferred support of AIR to a company called Harmon. You can get details about this at the Adobe AIR Development forum (https://forums.adobe.com/community/air/development).

There have also been a number of discussions on that forum about alternative options. HAXE gets a lot of mentions. I suggest that you do some reading on the forum.

Also, you should definitely look at Apache Royale (https://royale.apache.org/) which could be described as "next generation Flex" and is designed for precisely your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that flash application can be converted to a projector file. It requires FLASH standalone player. Will Adobe provide support for FLASH Standalone player after 2020? Also, Please let me know if you know any document or website link which details migrating Flex application to AIR.

Comment: If we just continued to use an old version of chrome (ie. IT disabled browser updates for a few months), would flash websites still work correctly?  Seems like browsers are simply going to disable flash support, no?

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/08/30/update-removing-flash-microsoft-edge-internet-explorer/#PAAgpmTRlOOih0TO.97

Answer (score 0):

Flash player will stop being supported in most on the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge..) and many still not done converting their applications to adobe air or any other language.

A quick way to get around will be by replacing the browser with adobe air application hosting our original flex web application and that need **ZERO SECONDS** development time because we will not change our original app at all instead the Adobe Air Desktop Application will act as container when it can render both HTML & Flash.

Create a new `Flash Project` > Under Application Type Choose `Desktop (Runs In Adobe Air)` > `Next` > Application Server Type `None` > `Finish`

In the newly created project go to `Project Name` > `src` > `ProjectName.mxml` File and add the following:

`<mx:HTML id="container" width="100%" height="100%" location="{linkToYourFlexWebProject}/Main.html"></mx:HTML>`

this will let the Adobe Air Application open your application.

To finalize the steps please make sure to export Adobe Air Project as follows to avoid any browser flash player dependencies:

`Right-Click` > `Export` > `Release Build` > Export As `Signed application with captive runtime` > Create the certification key and assign it and you are done.

It will generate a folder with the name of your application when ever you double click the .exe file it will connect to your flex web application online server and will open irrespective if flash player being installed on the device or not even if you changed the date to 2021 where the switch will be trigger to stop supporting flash player this will keep working.

A full video demonstration available:
http://youtu.be/qknVIXAKXdQ?hd=1

Answer (score -3):

Options :

- HTML5 + JAVASCRIPT + CSS

Anything that flash does can now be replaced programmatically  with the above.

Think about it, Flash is a tool that uses Action Script, which is very much so like javascript languages ( ECMAScript ). Also, it easily manipulates colors, shapes, and sizes ( styles ). Moreover, it renders all of that in a medium ( HTML page ).

The only thing we as programmers need to worry about is to start coding! Because the `<canvas>` tag is still relatively new, perhaps we need to delve into that more. But be of good cheer! We still have till December of next year...

Comment: "Anything that flash does can now be replaced programmatically with the above." 

-- Surely NOT . You don't understand the so much pain when migrating Flex projects to HTML5. Darn frustrating and HTML5 can NOT 100% do what Flash/Flex do.