# How to make the flash executable work after January 12, 2021?

Tags: windows, flash, windows-update, end-of-life

The [Flash EOL](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) is January 12, 2021.  Does the Flash Player executable actually stop Flash from working or is it something that can be stopped by Group Policy (in the case of a browser) or WSUS Updates in the case of the up-coming update?

And if so - how can you make flash work after January 12, 2021?

Comment: Is it possible to block the port or make flash.ocx read only to prevent the update?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any problems with your routine, just explorers don't show flash contents, that you can use Ruffle.rs to show your content as solution

Answer (score 2):

According to the [adobe flash administrator guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/pdf/latest/flash_player_32_0_admin_guide.pdf) in page 28 - it may be possible to allow enterprise flash applications to run.

If the browser will not block you (e.g. if you are using chrome 87 and below or firefox 84 and below) - you may just edit the mmc.cfg as so:

```
EOLUninstallDisable=1
SilentAutoUpdateEnable=0
EnableAllowList=1
AutoUpdateDisable=1
ErrorReportingEnable=1
AllowListUrlPattern=https://YOUR_URL_HERE:8443
```

The mmc config is found in directory:

- MacOS: /Library/Application Support/Macromedia
- Windows x86: C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash
- Windows x64: C:\Windows\SysWow64\Macromed\Flash
- For chrome:

  - macOS: /Users//Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome//Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/System
  - for Win: %USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data//Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/System
  - for Linux : ~/.config/google-chrome/User Data//Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/System/

Comment: Flash Player contains a "time-bomb" starting from version greater than 32.0.0.363. Make sure that flash version is less than 32.0.0.363 for these changes to be effective.

Comment: Is it a different directory on Windows?  the one I'm looking at is: `%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\32.0.0.465` but there is no `System` folder in there.

Comment: @leeand00 Maybe you have multiple versions installd?

Comment: @HenryAloni Actually the vendor came through for us, they said that unbeknownst to us the program uses a Standalone Flash Player and they were able to replace it with the developer / debug version which doesn’t have the ticking time-bomb.

Comment: There's another option to use ruffle (a rust implemented flash player) - see https://ruffle.rs/

Answer (score 0):

Setting your time on 13 Jan will block flash content to be executed on flash Player plugin, showing this icon:

[image]